# Google Maps API Geometry Library failing to load

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use the Geometry Library from Google Maps API. The API was performing normally when just loading the Places Library but once I try include the Geometry Library it fails and returns: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function        %7Bmain,places%7D.js:55`

Here is how I load the API using require.js:

```
define([
    'async!//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry'
], function(){

}
```

In the network tab the url request is: `http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/11/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js` which is returning 200 but that file is where the error is coming from. Specifically on the line: `k.google.maps.Load(a,b{......})`

If anyone has any insight why this issue please let me know.

Comment: what's the actual Google Maps URL (minus your key) being called by your browser? (not just what your JS code is passing to the require framework)

Comment: I wonder if you need to URL encode the comma? Try replacing , with %2C

Comment: I have tried encoded URL but it did not work. Loading geometry alone fails as well.

Comment: what else are you trying to do with the geometry library? show us the rest of the code you're using to create the map etc

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am getting something similar. My app worked fine yesterday, but today I get `http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/11/main.js net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the order in which your bootstrap parameters are passed. i.e. instead of what you've done:

```
js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry
```

You should pass the libraries before your key:

```
js?libraries=places,geometry&key=MY_KEY&sensor=true
```

Comment: This was absolutely killing me for a good hour or two - THANK YOU. The one thing I would say is it should be `&key` instead of `?key` so I've submitted an edit but definitely +1 for saving the rest of my hair I haven't yet pulled out